# Extract information from a MS Word document via Ruby

Tags: ruby

is there any way to extract data form a MS Word document using Ruby? I'd only need to know the number of pages of a given document.

I couldn't find a library for this. Do you know of any way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Very good question, it is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu) gem:

```
require 'yomu'

data = File.read 'file.docx'
metadata = Yomu.read :metadata, data

puts metadata['Page-Count']
```

Comment: Looks like it does, latest release was a month ago: http://rubygems.org/gems/yomu/versions

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Windows, you can use [win32ole](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html). You can open the file with:

```
word = WIN32OLE.new('Word.Application')
word.Visible = true
document = word.Documents.Open('c:\WordDocs\MyWordFile.doc')
```

And, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959164/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-pages-in-a-microsoft-word-file-using-ruby) answer, you could get the number of pages with:

```
page_count = document.Range.ComputeStatistics(WdStatisticPages)
```