# Extract page number from Word document - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docx, caracal

I'm working on an application that generates a .docx document using [Caracal](https://github.com/trade-informatics/caracal) gem. I need a way to find out how many pages said document has, preferably directly from Caracal. Alternatively, I tried to use [Yomu](https://github.com/yomurb/yomu) gem to get the page count from the metadata, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22749759/5592704).  However, apparently the document I'm generating does not include the page count in its metadata. Thanks in advance!